# Tiny MCE editor only loaded with alert statement after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce

I have a dynamic application that makes heavy use of javascript and ajax calls. With each ajax request the server returns javascript code. The javascript does first something like $('#contentBox').append('here a lot of html with also an textarea').

After the append is the initialization for the TinyMCE editor. The problem is that this only works when I put also an alert after the initialization code. Thus

```
$('#editor').tinymce({
// options
});
alert('hello');
```

But when the alert is not in the code the editor isn't showed at all. How to solve this?

Comment: after some testing I found out this issue occurs only in Firefox. In Chrome and IE9 evertythings seems working well.

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid jQuery, try:

```
$('#editor').tinymce({...});
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest not to use the jQuery-build of tinymce. It is by far slower than the normal build!!! (it is very slow when typing)
I suggest you use the normal tinymce build, but also load the regular jQuery library on the page - this is much more performant. In that case you can use the regular initialization function

```
tinymce.init({
    // options here
});
```